# How do I loop through two models to get attribute differences in a django template?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I am trying to figure out how to get the attribute differences from two different django models.  They have common attributes, and I want to compare the common attributes to see the differences.  I have managed to define both querysets with values and I can get the primary attribute fine.  The problem is when I am trying to loop through both of the models and get the attribute values and compare them.

My view...

I'm using a class based detailview...

```
class AuthorDetailView(LoginRequiredMixin,DetailView):
    model = Author
    context_object_name = 'author_detail'
    template_name = 'author_detail.html'

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    author = Author.objects.filter(author__id=self.object.pk).values('author_name','publisher_name')
    books =  Book.objects.filter(book__id=self.object.pk).values('author_name','publisher_name')
```

I have done something like this in my template...

```
  {% for i in books.all %}
    {% if i not in author.all %}
      {% if i.author_name %}
        Author Name :{{ i.author_name }}.
      {% endif %}
    {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
```

The above works.  The problem I'm having is when I try to do something like...

```
  {% for i in books.all %}
    {% if i not in author.all %}
        Author Name :{{ i.author_name }}.           
    {% endif %}
    {% for j in author.all %}
      {% if j.publishers.name != i.author_name %}
            Print Don't Match
       {% endif %}
    {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
```

I tried the above example and it doesn't produce output.  I've confirmed the values are identical, but I can't seem to get the template to show me the attribute differences.  I can see the main records that don't match by comparing the querysets, but getting to the next level of attributes is proving challenging.  Thanks in advance for any ideas.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if that's gonna help, but i tried YOUR way html with simple lists and it is working:

```
def view(request):
    l1 = [1,2]
    l2 = [2,3]
    context = {'l1':l1, 'l2':l2}
    return render(request, 'lists.html',context)

 {% for i in l1 %}

    {% if i not in l2 %}    
        the number :{{ i }} is not in both lists.<br>     
    {%else %}
        the number :{{ i }} is  in both lists.<br> 
    {% endif %}
    
    {% for j in l2 %}
        {% if j != i %}
            {{ i }} and {{ j }} are not equal.<br>   
        {%else %}
            {{ i }} and {{ j }} are equal.<br> 
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}

 {% endfor %}
```

which gave the result

```
1 and 2 are not equal.
1 and 3 are not equal.
the number :2 is in both lists.
2 and 2 are equal.
2 and 3 are not equal.
```

so maybe the problem is in this line

```
{% if j.publishers.name != i.author_name %},
```

with publishers.name or thw re-arrangemnt of the for loops, hope that can help somehow.

Comment: Playing with the loops now.  Thanks for the thought.

Comment: Yeah this totally works with simple lists and integers.  My problem is that I'm trying to do this with two different querysets and I believe that's why I'm having a hard time.   I've tried to get the values out of the querysets but that seems to be where my issue lies.

Answer (score 1):

Taking a guess here:

view:

```
class AuthorDetailView(LoginRequiredMixin,DetailView):
    model = Author
    context_object_name = 'author'   # you already get the author here
    template_name = 'author_detail.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        ctx = super(AuthorDetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        ctx["books"] = Book.objects.filter(book__id=self.object.pk) 
        return ctx
```

template (wild stab at what you want):

```
 {% for book in books %}
    {% if book.author_name != author.author_name %}
           Author Name :{{ book.author_name }}.           
    {% endif %}
 {% endfor %}
 
 {% for publisher in author.publishers.all %}
    {% if publisher.name != author.author_name
             Print Don't Match
    {% endif %}
 {% endfor %}
```

In the DetailView you get one model, in this case an Author. If you want all the authors, you'll have to add them all in get_context_data.  The way to access all the publishers is different than iterating the authors.

Answer (score 0):

The problem appears to lie in the fact that in your view you are setting both `books` and `author` to a queryset of dictionaries with `author_name` and `publisher_name` but in your template you are not using the correct field name...in other words:

```
{% if j.publishers.name != i.author_name %}
should be
{% if j.publisher_name != i.author_name %}
```

Also, since your are sending querysets to your template, I'm pretty sure you don't have to use `.all` You can just do this:

```
{% for i in books %}
instead of
{% for i in books.all %}
```

Won't make much difference but thought I'd mention anyway

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I think this is the final answer....I ultimately wound up looping through my querysets in my template.  Because this was a detailview I was able to access the querysets and the variables I wanted by looping with the syntax outlined below.

```
   {% for author in author_detail.author_set.all %}
      {% for book in book_detail.book_set.all %}
         {% if author.author_name %}
            {% if book.book_name in author.book_name %}
              {% if author.book_name == book.book_name %}
                {% elif author.book_name != book.book_name %}
                    {{ author.author_name }}
                {% endif %}
            {% endif %}
         {% endif %}
       {% endfor %}
   {% endfor %}
```

In this case I defined my context object name as company_detail in my DetailView.  The nested looping made this one tricky.  Thanks for all of the feedback!